# Animation must be non-nil in Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to create a CCSprite subclass called Enemy

```
#import "Enemy.h"


@implementation Enemy
{
    CCSprite* ant;
    CCAnimation *walkAnim ;
}

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"char.plist"];
    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"char.png"];
    [self addChild:spriteSheet];

    NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i=1; i<=3; i++) {
        [walkAnimFrames addObject:
         [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"antNormal_%d.png",i]]];
    }

    walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];
    self = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"antNormal_1.png"];
    CCAction* walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim]];
    [self runAction:walkAction];

    return self;
}
@end
```

and then in my gamelayer I have the enemies added like this

```
    enemies=[[CCArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        Enemy* ant=[[Enemy alloc] init];
        [ant setPosition:ccp(100*i,100)];
        [enemies addObject:ant];
    }
```

But this is causing the program to crash on start with the error

`'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Animate: argument Animation must be non-nil'`

If I comment out the CCAction though, the enemies display correctly, just without animation(obviously). Not sure how to solve this at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't speak to Cocos2d specifically, there's several things wrong in your `init` method from an ObjC standpoint that probably contribute to the problem.

1. `self` is set self twice. The second one creates a **new instance** of the class and clobbers the old one. You should only set self to the result of an `init` method, not a class factory method
2. `self` is not checked for nil. You should always check `self` for nil **before** setting any ivars. If the `init` method you call fails, if will be nil and your app will crash.
3. `walkAnim` is not retained, it will be released at a later time and your app will crash when you try to use it. It must be retained.
4. Do not call methods on `self` in your custom `init` methods. By definition, your object is not in a fully initialized state inside `init` methods. Strange things can occur if you call methods on `self`. Other `init` methods are an exception.

While I cannot guarantee this is free of bugs, as I am not personally familiar with Cocoas2d, this should get you closer to what you want:

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [CCSprite initWithSpriteFrameName:@"antNormal_1.png"];

    if (self)
    {
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"char.plist"];
        CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"char.png"];
        [self addChild:spriteSheet];

        NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i=1; i<=3; i++) {
            [walkAnimFrames addObject:
             [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"antNormal_%d.png",i]]];
        }

        walkAnim = [[CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f] retain];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)startWalkAction
{
        CCAction* walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim]];
        [self runAction:walkAction];
}
```

And then add enemies like this:

```
enemies=[[CCArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    Enemy* ant=[[Enemy alloc] init];
    [ant setPosition:ccp(100*i,100)];
    [ant startWalkAction];
    [enemies addObject:ant];
}
```

Comment: dont forget to release walkAnim in your dealloc method.

Comment: Or any time you assign an object to it for that matter. I prefer using properties to handle memory management, though with a game there *may* be performance reasons to avoid a method call. Still, you can just use the ivar straight up if you have a property.